Mini PC bootloader control using a laptop
I just bought an used Beelink BT3 mini pc. I've started the Windows factory reset process using the mouse only. After reboot from the PC, it is now in the bootloader part and I'm asked if I want to continue but it only allows inputs from keyboard or wired phones, which I have neither.
I do have another laptop, an ethernet cable and also a mouse. Am I able to do anything with this?

You do not state the mini PC can use Ethernet in booting, so why ask? As for USB from PC-to-PC, that requires specialized equipment, far more difficult to find than a keyboard.

I don't know why you don't have a keyboard. They are a necessity in almost all things you would do online or with technology. I recommend getting one.

'wired phones' makes no sense in this context

Are we talking about bios/uefi or that windows 8 style 'pick what you want to boot from' menu?

@JourneymanGeek the Beelink bootloader gives the option to use wired phones volume up and down to select things.

Many pre-boot environments require a keyboard, and when they do it is not an option. While you may not WANT to use a keyboard, you may simply not have that choice.
Get a keyboard and proceed.

@daemonic, the edit is fine, but the initial phrasing was intended. OP does not simply "not want" to use a keyboard, they "want to not use a keyboard", which is awkward I think because it isn't a phrasing using so often, but it emphasizes that they are wanting a negative.
